# Getting/Storing/Accessing the Currently Logged In User and Their Roles/Permissions

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using next-auth for authentication and I have a way of storing and retrieving a logged in user's roles and permissions. What I'm not sure of is the best practice for when I should be retrieving all of this data.

For example:

- Should I just get all this when they log in and store it somewehere? Where?
- Should I use the context api to store this in state and wrap the entire app so that all components can have access to this?
- Should I use middleware to get all this data on each request?

Sorry for a basic question but I'm quite new to this. What would be the best practice for this?

Unsure of the best practice

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please post some code if you have done any example? Also, related to your question, please check this link https://forbytes.com/blog/react-authentication-best-practices/